# Driving LED downlights in series fails

Tags: led, led-driver, constant-current

**Problem**

I'm having trouble understanding why driving two or more of my generic Chinese brand 18 W LED downlights in series results in the LED driver shutting down due to overload, while the driver should meet all the requirements to do so.

The equipment I'm trying to get working are

- 2x 18 W LED Downlights, generic brand, rated for 300 mA
- 1x 90 W LED Driver ([Osram OTi DALI 90/220…240/1A0 LT2 L](https://www.osram.com/ecat/OPTOTRONIC%20Intelligent%20-%20DALI%20(non-isolated)-Constant%20Current%20Linear%20+%20Area%20-%20Dimmable-Constant%20Current%20Linear%20-%20Indoor-LED%20Drivers-Digital%20Systems/com/en/GPS01_3183480/ZMP_1089786/))

Driving a single lamp at ~**320 mA** current works fine, and so does driving two lamps in parallel at **~640 mA** current.

[image: Lights connected in parallel]

I measured the voltage to be **~56 V** when driving at the nominal current, so in theory when two lamps are in series it should be around **~112 V**?

When connected in series, the voltage goes straight up to **240 V+** (my cheap meter showed up to 244 V) after which the driver shuts down due to overvoltage (blinking once in a while to see if the overload situation persists).

[image: Lights connected in series]

I also took one of the lamps apart, the lamp itself is just flexible strip of SMD2835 LEDs connected in **5p18s** layout (so 90 LEDs total), nothing fancy there.

**Why drive in series?**

While driving the lamps in parallel works, my understanding after some researching on the internet is that it's generally not recommended to drive constant current lights in parallel. Though, the driver manufacturer has some examples with the lamps wired in parallel, so perhaps it's not as bad as I understood?

There is still one downside though, I'm limited to just 3 lights when driving in parallel if I want to drive at the rated 300 mA current, while in series it should in theory be possible to drive up to 4.

**Why it fails?**

My best guess (as pretty much a total novice to electronics) would be that the flexible LED strip itself can't handle the higher voltage needed to drive the two lamps in series, essentially shorting the circuit and thus the driver supplying the max voltage before shutting down.

I've pretty much come to terms with the that my only option is to drive them in parallel if I want to use the equipment I already have, but at least an explanation why this is happening would be great.

Comment: That seems pretty strange. You've tested both of the lamps individually, right? If pushing 320 mA through one lamp works, and pushing 320 mA through the other lamp also works, then pushing 320 mA through both lamps in series should also work, because pushing 320 mA through both lamps in series _is_ pushing 320 mA through one and pushing 320 mA through the other. The lamps don't have any way of knowing whether or not there's another lamp connected in series... do they?

Comment: Livari, it sounds like one of the strips is connect in reverse ie. + where - should be. First try reversing the polarity. if this does not work try reversing the polarity of just one of the two strips in series. If they do not work reverse the power connections.

Comment: One lamp has 25A inrush current, two in parallel have 50A inrush current... Maybe they're causing problems for each other on start up because of that. And I would consider OSRAM a good name.

Comment: Can you put in a picture of the power electronics circuit board (both sides)?